# Why is there no time dilation for frequency of a wave?

Tags: special-relativity

Since frequency of a wave is a function of time, then for a particular ray of the wave, why would the frequency remain the same when observed from a moving reference frame? The frequency should change according to time dilation. No?

Comment: [Who says it doesn't?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the frequency does change. This is a component of the [relativistic Doppler effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect).

The effect comes from two sources: first, there is the classical (nonrelativistic) Doppler effect, which comes from the fact that successive crests of the wave are emitted from closer and closer to the receiver (I use the case where the emitter is moving toward the receiver). This changes the frequency as

$$f_\text{received} = \biggl(1 + \frac{v}{c}\biggr)f_\text{emitted}$$

That part has nothing to do with relativity; it's responsible for the Doppler effect we hear in sound waves, for example.

Then on top of that, for light, the frequency is subject to the Lorentz transformation. Since frequency is the reciprocal of a time, it has the inverse of the transformation for time, namely $f\to \gamma f$. So the combined result from the two effects is

$$f_\text{received} = \gamma\biggl(1 + \frac{v}{c}\biggr)f_\text{emitted} = \sqrt{\frac{c + v}{c - v}}f_\text{emitted}$$

for relative approach.

Comment: Being a BOF of many years training I would have preferred to see this proved directly using the Lorentz transforms. If I get time I'll update my answer ...

Comment: Yeah, it is nice to see a proof, but I didn't have much time to put into this. It's just what I could type up in a couple minutes or so.

Comment: Is the relativistic Doppler effect applicable for rays reflected from an object. i.e. is it applicable for an incoherent light source....

Comment: @Physicsman Yes.

Comment: @Physicsman why did you ask if you don't want to accept the answer? In any case daaxix is right (and you are wrong), the effect applies to _all_ electromagnetic waves.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky. I will accept the answer the moment I am fully satisfied that it is correct. Can someone explain to me why the Doppler Effect applies to reflected light? The scenario is that there a light source pointed at a wall. This leads to Diffuse deflection (incoherent light) as observed from a stationary frame. There is no formation of a wave front. If you can point me somewhere that shows that RDE would be applicable for a single photon, I will happily accept your annswer :-)

Comment: @Physicsman Oh, when I said "accept the answer" I didn't mean the green checkmark, I meant mentally accepting what daaxix told you about how the relativistic Doppler effect applies to even incoherent light rays. As for a justification: the derivation of the RDE does not assume the existence of a wavefront, only of a definite frequency. But then you can decompose any light wave, even incoherent light, into a sum of sinusoidal components with definite frequencies, and it is these components that have their frequencies shifted according to the equation given in my post.

Comment: After much more reading, RDE is based on the classical Doppler Effect and obviously the classical Doppler Effect needs wavefronts in its derivation. So I don't see how RDE wont. For incoherent light wont the superimposing waves cancel each other out? I am reopening this question.

Comment: @Physicsman I'm not sure what you mean, the derivation of the classical (or relativistic) Doppler effect which I gave in my post does not require the existence of a wavefront.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky. I meant the  classical (nonrelativistic) Doppler effect depends on wavefronts, specifically the time between successive wave fronts.

My concern is that in RDE, since those wavefronts don't exist, should a single ray (stream of photons) still be taken as a wavefront. I guess you are right. The observed effect for this ray would be the same as a wavefront.

Comment: @Physicsman no, I know what you meant, but I'm saying it's not correct. The classical Doppler effect does not depend on wavefronts. And it's not justified to say that wavefronts don't exist in the relativistic case. They exist in the same circumstances where they exist in the nonrelativistic treatment.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky Of course the classical doppler effect depends on wavefronts:
http://www.usna.edu/Users/physics/mungan/Scholarship/DopplerEffect.pdf

Comment: @PhysicsMan no it doesn't. That PDF mentions wavefronts, but it's not required for the proof. All you need, as I said, is some periodic structure to the wave. (I guess this depends on what you mean by "wavefront." If you're using the term to mean any generic periodic feature of the waveform, then yes, it does depend on wavefronts.)

Answer (score 3):

Both the the frequency and wavelength change. Obviously so because $\nu\lambda = c$ and $c$ is a constant. If you have a specific example of where you think the frequency doesn't change update your question with the details and I'll update my answer to address it.